# Initializing logistic regression coefficients when using the Spark dataset-based ML APIs?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

By default, logistic regression training initializes the coefficients to be all-zero. However, I would like to initialize the coefficients myself. This would be useful, for example, if a previous training run crashed after several iterations -- I could simply restart training with the last known set of coefficients.

Is this possible with any of the dataset/dataframe-based APIs, preferably Scala?

Looking at the Spark source code, it seems that there *is* a method `setInitialModel` to initialize the model and its coefficients, [but it's unfortunately marked as private](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/267aca5bd5042303a718d10635bc0d1a1596853f/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/LogisticRegression.scala#L315).

The RDD-based API seems to allow initializing coefficients: one of the overloads of `LogisticRegressionWithSGD.run(...)` accepts an `initialWeights` vector. However, I would like to use the dataset-based API instead of the RDD-based API because (1) the former supports elastic net regularization (I couldn't figure out how to do elastic net with the RDD-based logistic regression) and (2) because [the RDD-based API is in maintenance mode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/ml-guide.html).

I could always try using reflection to call that private `setInitialModel` method, but I would like to avoid this if possible (and maybe that wouldn't even work... I also can't tell if `setInitialModel` is marked private for a good reason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to override the method. Yes you will need to copy that class into your own work area. That's fine: *do not fear*.

When you build your project -either via `maven` or `sbt` - your local copy of the class will "win" and shade the one in `MLlib`.  Fortunately the other classes in that same package will *not* be shaded.

I have used this approach many times with overriding Spark classes: actually your build times should be small as well.