# Initialize spark ml Logistic Regression with an already trained model

Tags: apache-spark, logistic-regression, apache-spark-ml

I wonder if anyone has managed to fix what is questioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44892400/initializing-logistic-regression-coefficients-when-using-the-spark-dataset-based/44896752#44896752).

My experiment works as follows:
 - Train a LogisticRegression with a dataset of a feature vector of 2 positions (1 feature of 2 categories) (each row can only have a feature vector with just one position different from 0). As a result, the model has 2 coefficients and an intercept.
 - Build a new LogisticRegression passing model1 as the starting point (overriding *setInitialModel* method by making it public)
 - Train the new LogisticRegression with a training dataset where only one category appears.

As a result, I would expect two coefficients, one equivalent to its value in model1 and the second one with the value modified because of the second training dataset.
However, I obtain a coefficients vector with only one coefficient different from 0, which is the one referring to the category appearing in the second training dataset.

Any ideas? What am I missing to override?